# Add matching column from index file to a csv

Tags: awk

I have a file `index.txt` with data like:

```
2013/10/13-121 f19f26f09691c2429cb33456cf64f867
2013/10/17-131 583d3936c814c1bf4e663fe1688fe4a3
2013/10/20-106 0f7082e2bb7224aad0bd7a6401532f56
2013/10/10-129 33f7592a4ad22f9f6d63d6a17782d023
......
```

And a second file in CSV format with data like:

```
2013/10/13-121, DLDFWSXDR, 15:33, 18:21, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965
2013/10/17-131, DLDFWXDR, 11:05, 15:08, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965
2013/10/20-106, DLSDXDR, 12:08, 13:06, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965
2013/10/10-129, DLXDAE, 15:33, 18:46, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965
```

Now i need a solution to add the MD5SUM  at the end of the CSV when the ID (first column) is a match in the index file or vice versa , so at the end the file should look like this:

```
2013/10/13-121, DLDFWSXDR, 15:33, 18:21, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, f19f26f09691c2429cb33456cf64f867
2013/10/17-131, DLDFWXDR, 11:05, 15:08, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 583d3936c814c1bf4e663fe1688fe4a3
2013/10/20-106, DLSDXDR, 12:08, 13:06, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 0f7082e2bb7224aad0bd7a6401532f56
2013/10/10-129, DLXDAE, 15:33, 18:46, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 33f7592a4ad22f9f6d63d6a17782d023
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `join` command.

```
join  <(sort file1.csv | sed 's/$/,/g') <(sort index.txt | sed 's/ /, /g')

2013/10/10-129, DLXDAE, 15:33, 18:46, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 33f7592a4ad22f9f6d63d6a17782d023
2013/10/13-121, DLDFWSXDR, 15:33, 18:21, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, f19f26f09691c2429cb33456cf64f867
2013/10/17-131, DLDFWXDR, 11:05, 15:08, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 583d3936c814c1bf4e663fe1688fe4a3
2013/10/20-106, DLSDXDR, 12:08, 13:06, Normal, No, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/22551965, 0f7082e2bb7224aad0bd7a6401532f56
```

- `sort t1 | sed 's/$/,/g'` sort file1.csv and sufix it by comma.
- `sort t2 | sed 's/ /, /g'` sort index.txt and replace the delimitor
- Then use join command (by default 1st field).

Comment: Brilliant if IDs and their count are identical; what if they differ?

Comment: Thanks RudiC, thats exactly the point, the Index file i have has 11785 uniq IDs and the csv has 139898 lines with multiple same IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` without sorting any file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1' index.txt FS=', ' OFS=', ' file.csv
```

The first block statement allows the first file `index.txt` to be copied into the array `a`.

The second block statement append the content of the array `a` at the end of the line of file `file.csv` if the key (first field of the file) is part of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try also - should IDs in first and second file differ - :

```
awk 'NR == FNR {S[$1] = $2; next} {print $0 FS " " S[$1]}' file1 FS="," file2
```